# Dynamically generate a <li> list item html sections for an array of objects

Tags: php, html

I am beginner in PHP, to be frank, just started a couple of days before.
I want to create the below html section dynamically using php.

```
<div class="main">
<ul id="og-grid" class="og-grid">

<li>
    <a href="#" data-largesrc="imgURL of index[1] item" data-title="title of index[1] item"
       data-description="descrition of index[1] item">
        <img src="imgUrl of index[1] item" alt="img01"/>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#" data-largesrc="imgUrl of index[2] item" data-title="title of index[2] item"
       data-description="descrition of index[2] item">
        <img src="imgUrl of index[2] item" alt="img02"/>
    </a>
</li>

// Like this for a size of an array

<li>
     <a href="#" data-largesrc="imgUrl of index[n] item" data-title="title of index[n] item"
           data-description="descrition of index[n] item">
            <img src="imgUrl of index[n] item" alt="img02"/>
     </a>
</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

This is what i tried, but the code isn't complete as I am stuck on this

```
echo '<div class="main">';
echo '<ul id="og-grid" class="og-grid">';

for ($row = 0; $row < sizeof($vodAssetArray); $row++)
{
    echo '<li><a href="#"><img src =""></img></a></li>';
}
```

Could you please help me on this.

Comment: So how should we help you? What's your error?

Comment: There is no error. I am stuck with this code as I dont know how to proceed on this?

Comment: Proceed on what? What do you want to do? echo something? access element or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking at PHP [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Basically You need and array of classes (or arrays), for example, basic class could be something like:

```
class Item {
    public $title;
    public $description;
    public $url;
}
```

Then create new objects and put them in array:

```
$picture = new Item();
$picture->url = "http://linktomypicture.com";
$picture->title = "Sample Title for picture";
$picture->description = "Sample description for my picture";
$array_of_pictures[] = $picture;
```

And iterate through them:

```
foreach ($array_of_pictures as $picture) {
    echo "<li>";
    echo "<a href='{$picture->url}' data-largesrc='{$picture->url}'";
    echo "data-title='{$picture->title}'";
    echo "data-description='{$picture->descrition}'>";
    echo "<img src='{$picture->url}' alt='{$picture->title}'/>";
    echo "</a>";
    echo "</li>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

open the php scope and close them like this. The li items will be generated inside the for() scopes

```
<div class="main">
<ul id="og-grid" class="og-grid">
<?php for($i = 0; $i < $listLebght; $i++)
{
?>

<li>
    <a href="#" data-largesrc="array->imgUrl" data-title="array->title"
       data-description="array->descrition">
        <img src="<?php echo $src; ?>" alt="img02"/>
    </a>
</li>
<?php
}
?>
</ul>
</div>
```